# How to get Alfresco login ticket without user password, but with impersonating user with user principal name (UPN)

Tags: c#, authentication, alfresco, impersonation, defaultnetworkcredentials

I'm writing a DLL that has function for getting Alfresco login ticket without using user password, using only a user principal name (UPN). I’m calling alfresco REST API service */wcservice*. I use NTLM in Alfresco.

I’m impersonating users using `WindowsIdentity` constructor as explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998351.aspx#paght000023_impersonatingbyusingwindowsidentity. I checked and user is properly impersonated (I checked `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` property).

After impersonating a user, I try to make `HttpWebRequest` and set its credentials with `CredentialsCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials`. I get the error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

When I use `new NetworkCredential("username", "P@ssw0rd")` to set request credentials, I get Alfresco login ticket (`HttpStatusCode.OK`, 200).

Is there any way that I can get Alfresco login ticket without user password?

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
private string GetTicket(string UPN) {
 WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(UPN);
 WindowsImpersonationContext context = null;

 try {
  context = identity.Impersonate();

  MakeWebRequest();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
  return e.Message + Environment.NewLine + e.StackTrace;
 }
 finally {
  if (context != null) {
   context.Undo();
  }
 }
}

private string MakeWebRequest() {
 string URI = "http://alfrescoserver/alfresco/wcservice/mg/util/login";


 HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URI) as HttpWebRequest;

 request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(1);

 //request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "p@ssw0rd"); // It works with this
 request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;  // It doesn’t work with this
 //request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;    // It doesn’t work with this either

 try {
  using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse) {
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

   return sr.ReadToEnd();
  }
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
  return (e.Message + Environment.NewLine + e.StackTrace);
 }
}
```

Here are records from Alfresco stdout.log (if it helps in any way):

```
17:18:04,550  DEBUG [app.servlet.NTLMAuthenticationFilter] Processing request: /alfresco/wcservice/mg/util/login SID:7453F7BD4FD2E6A61AD40A31A37733A5
17:18:04,550  DEBUG [web.scripts.DeclarativeRegistry] Web Script index lookup for uri /mg/util/login took 0.526239ms
17:18:04,550  DEBUG [app.servlet.NTLMAuthenticationFilter] New NTLM auth request from 10.**.**.** (10.**.**.**:1229)
17:18:04,566  DEBUG [app.servlet.NTLMAuthenticationFilter] Processing request: /alfresco/wcservice/mg/util/login SID:7453F7BD4FD2E6A61AD40A31A37733A5
17:18:04,566  DEBUG [web.scripts.DeclarativeRegistry] Web Script index lookup for uri /mg/util/login took 0.400909ms
17:18:04,566  DEBUG [app.servlet.NTLMAuthenticationFilter] Received type1 [Type1:0xe20882b7,Domain:<NotSet>,Wks:<NotSet>]
17:18:04,566  DEBUG [app.servlet.NTLMAuthenticationFilter] Client domain null
17:18:04,675  DEBUG [app.servlet.NTLMAuthenticationFilter] Sending NTLM type2 to client - [Type2:0x80000283,Target:AlfrescoServerA,Ch:197e2631cc3f9e0a]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved the problem!

I believe that we had a [double-hop problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx).

This is what had to be done to solve this problem:

1. User that runs my DLL must be **Windows Server 2003 domain
   user**
2. Service that uses my DLL must have
   registered **Service Principal Name** in
   Domain controller with user that
   runs it (user that runs my DLL)
3. User that runs my DLL must not have
   **Account is sensitive and cannot be
   delegated** option selected in Domain
   controller
4. User that runs my DLL must have
   **Trust this user for delegation to
   any service (Kerberos only)** or **Trust
   this user for delegation to
   specified services only** option
   selected in Domain controller (if
   the user is in Windows Server 2003
   functional domain this option is
   available only when you register
   Service Principal Name with this
   user)
5. User that runs my DLL must have **TrustedToAuthForDelegation** user account control (UAC) set to true
6. Computer that runs service that uses
   my DLL must have **Trust computer for
   delegation to any service (Kerberos
   only)** or **Trust computer for
   delegation to specified services
   only** option selected in Domain
   Controller

This all (and more) is explained in Microsoft document [Troubleshooting Kerberos Delegation](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=99b0f94f-e28a-4726-bffe-2f64ae2f59a2&displaylang=en). It contains:

- checklist for Active Directory,
- checklist for Client application,
- checklist for Middle tier,
- checklist for Back-end

plus

- configuration examples for common
  scenarios.

Setting **TrustedToAuthForDelegation** user account control (UAC) is done in PowerShell by Active Directory cmdlet explained [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617249.aspx).

You can read more about [Windows Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647076.aspx).

Of course, Alfresco must have Kerberos login enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is not possible for Alfresco. Only if you use special authentication subsystem where exists this 'impersonal' user.

Try this, because 'guest' user is transversal for all subsystem authentication.

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("guest", "guest");

And the URI, something like this:

string URI = "http://alfrescoserver/alfresco/s/api/login or whatever you propose.

Good luck.
Paco

Comment: If I use http://alfrescoserver/alfresco/s/api/login, I need to supply user's password as parameter which I'm trying to avoid.
I believe that what I’m trying to do should be possible. All I need to do is to get right credentials for HTTP request. Maybe I have double-hop problem (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx), and I’m reading Microsoft’s document Troubleshooting Kerberos Delegation (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=99b0f94f-e28a-4726-bffe-2f64ae2f59a2&displaylang=en) to try to resolve it.
I still need help.