# Connecting Alfresco and Liferay with a specified user

Tags: liferay, alfresco, cmis

I am trying to connect Alfresco (4.2) with Liferay (6.1.1). Everything works without problems if I use Documents and Media Portlet.

My problem is I need to use a specified user to connect to Alfresco and not the logged user.

I have tried to add some properties on `portal-ext.properties`, like `dl.store.cmis.credentials.username`, and `dl.store.cmis.credentials.password`, but without luck.

Can someone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Alfresco login ticket without user password, but with impersonating user with user principal name (UPN)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627797/how-to-get-alfresco-login-ticket-without-user-password-but-with-impersonating-u)